# Powers of the Laplacian matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, graph-theory

Given a graph with an adjacency matrix $\bf A$, powers of this matrix give the number of walks from vertices. That is, $({\bf A}^k)_{ij}$ gives the number of walks from nodes $i$ to $j$ in $k$ steps. Is there any nice physical iterpertation for the powers of the [Laplacian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplacian_matrix) matrix?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In my opinion, it is not natural to take powers of the Laplacian in isolation. That is, the Laplacian should not be thought of as a linear operator that one is interested in iterating. There are two points of view that I know of about what the Laplacian "is":

- It's the matrix representation of the quadratic form $\sum_{(v, w) \in E} (f(v) - f(w))^2$ where $f$ is a function on the vertices. Matrices of quadratic forms are not meant to be composed.
- It generates a one-dimensional Lie algebra acting on the space of functions on the vertices. This perspective is relevant to the answer I gave to [this math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/19292/connection-between-graphs-and-the-eigenvectors-of-their-matrix-representation/19298#19298) question, where by using the Laplacian to define certain differential equations it becomes natural to *exponentiate*, rather than take powers of, the Laplacian. The powers appear in the exponential, but indirectly.

Comment: Thanks Qiaochu, I had read that answer before and I have seen the use of the Laplacian in the mapping of DE to graphs. The idea of L as an operator (rather then a plain matrix) seems to validate the study of it's eigenvalues more so then the adj. matrix. However, by looking at the matrix exponential as a kind of series expansion, can't one point to one of the terms and ask what they mean? You are allowed to do so in a normal series expansion of one-dimensional function (and it makes sense there), why not in this case?

Comment: @Hooked: sure, but I'm not sure this gets you anything with as direct an interpretation as the powers of the adjacency matrix.